# Nulling property in Entity Framework entity taking precedent over assigning ID

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I currently have a situation where I clear an entity reference from another entity, then assign it back later.  When I execute UnitOfCommit.Commit it always does the NULL update and not the 1111.  Is there a way around this?

**Sequence**

```
// Clear Reference
divisionTeamPool.DivisionTeam = null;
divisionTeamPool.DivisionTeamId = null;

// No Commit Yet, Assign Same DivisionTeamId
divisionTeamPool.DivisionTeamId = 1111;

// Commit
UnitOfCommit.Commit();
```

**Class**

```
[Table("DivisionTeamPool", Schema = "GrassrootsHoops")]
public class DivisionTeamPool : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int? DivisionTeamId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("DivisionTeamId")]
    public virtual DivisionTeam DivisionTeam { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can't modify the KEY name : [ForeignKey("DivisionTeamId")].  You have to create a new KEY and delete the old key.

Comment: Take a look at the "Relation fixup" section of [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/change-tracking/relationship-changes). Buried in the text is a caution to "Avoid manipulating both navigations and FK values." **Speculation:** Entity Framework might defer fixup processing in some cases and it might not occur until the entity is saved. If the FK property has changed, EF will update the navigation properties. If a navigation property has changed, the FK property is fixed. If both have changed, EF might not know which was intended and may prioritize the navigation property.

Comment: I suggest that you modify the code to consistently either only update the FK property or only update the navigation in both pieces of code. Performing a save between the two operations might also resolve the issue, but this may could briefly leave the database in an unwanted state, so I would not recommend it..

Answer (score 0):

When working with navigation properties I recommend using either FKs or Navigation Properties, never both. The reason is that as you've seen there are two sources of truth and the behaviour you will experience will be situational, which can cause unexpected behaviour appearing.

If you have a FK property and a Navigation property, the behaviour for updates will depend on whether an instance of the navigation property is being tracked or not.

Take the following example:

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var division = context.Divisions
        .Single(x => x.DivisionId == divisionId);

    division.DivisionTeamId = newTeamId;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

IF the division's existing Team ID was "1" and the new team ID was "2" then the Division row would have it's FK updated on the `SaveChanges` as you might expect. However now look and the next example:

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var division = context.Divisions
        .Include(x => x.DivisionTeam)
        .Single(x => x.DivisionId == divisionId);

    division.DivisionTeamId = newTeamId;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This example is virtually identical, except we eager load the DivisionTeam navigation property. However now, after saving the changes, the Division's team ID will still be "1", not "2". The reason is that in the first example the Division's team reference wasn't loaded, so EF will respect the FK property change. When the reference is loaded, it takes precedence. To change the DivisionTeam in both examples reliably:

```
using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
    var newTeam = context.DivisionTeams.Single(x => x.DivisionTeamId == newTeamId);
    var division = context.Divisions
        .Include(x => x.DivisionTeam)
        .Single(x => x.DivisionId == divisionId);

    division.DivisionTeam = newTeam;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Now it might seem ok to assume you can just change relationships with the FK as long as you don't eager-load the navigation property, and where a DbContext is freshly scoped like the above examples, that is generally fine. However, when a DbContext is injected having possibly done other operations, you can still get related navigation properties filled in by the DbContext even without eager loading if the DbContext happens to be tracking any of those related entities.  For example:

```
// Some code higher in the call stack of the request:

var divisionTeam = context.DivisionTeam.Where(x => x.DivisionTeamId == newTeamId);

// Then later when you are doing the update.

var division = context.Divisions
    .Single(x => x.DivisionId == divisionId);

division.DivisionTeamId = newTeamId;
```

Even if we didn't eager load the Division Team with the Division, some earlier code may have loaded that team, and when getting the Divison the DbContext will populate any references related to it that it happens to be tracking. In this case you'd get the same behaviour where the team ID wouldn't get updated. This can be a frustrating bug as it's completely situational where one situation might see a related row being associated, while another instance seems to work.

For this reason I recommend that when using navigation properties, use shadow properties for the FKs and update the associations using the navigation properties. If you need to do "fast" bulk updates then consider using a bounded DbContext with entities using FKs rather than navigation properties and perform those updates using the FKs.